# How to make KDE Desktop stop creating notification 'The screen is being locked'

Tags: kde, notifications, kde-4

Is there a setting somewhere that tells KDE Power Management System to stop creating notifications whenever I put the computer to sleep? It is annoying, having my notification list full of 'The screen is being locked' messages.

Screenshot of 'The screen is being locked'

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You aren't the only one who thinks it's useless. The KDE developers are [removing this notification entirely in KDE 4.10](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=306781).

To disable it now, follow these steps:

1. Go to **System Settings**.

   [image]
2. Go to **Power Management**.

   [image]
3. On the left side, click **Advanced Settings**.

   [image]
4. On the right side, click the **Configure Notifications...** button.

   [image]
5. Select the notification **Performing a suspension job**.

   [image]
6. Disable all notifications related to this job, and then click **OK**.

   [image]

Comment: Thanks alot! It works! Except I like the sound that plays when KDE goes to sleep, etc. so I left the Play a sound box checked.